# Estimating a value from two factors

Tags: estimation

I want to meassure satisfaction per customers. I have to factors that define satisfaction:

- Amount of Incidents
- Sentiment-score per Incident

Sentiment-score is calculated with natural language processing sentiment analysis and is in the range of -1 (negative sentiment) and +1 (positiv sentiment)

Amount of Incidents is just the total number of Incidents.

I want to put those two numbers in combination, for example:

Amount of Incidents goes up by 20% & Average Sentiment over those Incidents stays the same -> Satisfactory -level goes down 5 Points

Amount of Incidents goes up by 20% & Average Sentiment over those Incidents worsens -> Satisfactory -level goes down 12 Points

etc.

What kind of math do i have to look into to combine those factors?
Sorry for the bad english and simple explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you believe that customer satisfaction is the the underlying cause of both of your variables (e.g. below)...

[image]

...then the technique you're looking for is factor analysis (with one latent factor). This estimates the effect of the common factor, *Satisfaction*, on your two variables, and lets you estimate the factor score as a weighted combination of the two variables.